# Assign single SPEI value for each city

Tags: python, spatial-join, kriging, climate, precipitation

I want to have a single value of [SPEI](https://spei.csic.es/) to every city of my map. As the SPEI data is gridded at 0.5 degree resolution, some cities o not have a point falling into its boundaries. My approach was to "downscale" SPEI to 5 min resolution and compute the average for each city. My code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
#Read shapefile of the state (MA)
MA = gpd.read_file ('https://github.com/kevinkuranyi/archive/raw/main/Maranhao.shp')
#SPEI data (2013)
spei_ma = gpd.read_file('https://github.com/kevinkuranyi/archive/raw/main/spei_ma.shp')
# Plot the map of MA
ax = MA.plot(alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k', facecolor='none')
#Plot the points within the boundaries of MA
spei_ma.plot(ax=ax, color='red', marker='o', markersize=5);
```

[image]

```
#Possible solution: downscale to 5 min resolution and compute the average for each city
#Read dataset gridded at 5 min resolution to downscale using nearest neighbor approach
data_5_min_ma = gpd.read_file('https://github.com/kevinkuranyi/archive/raw/main/data_5min_ma.shp')
#Spatial join to downscale
gdf = data_5_min_ma.to_crs(epsg=32723).sjoin_nearest(spei_ma.to_crs(epsg=32723))[['ID', 'spei','geometry']]
#Spatial join with cities
points_mun = gpd.sjoin(gdf.to_crs(epsg=32723), MA.to_crs(epsg=32723), how="inner")
#Compute average value for each city
spei_avg_ma=points_mun.groupby('CD_MUN')['spei'].mean()
spei_avg_ma = spei_avg_ma.reset_index()[['CD_MUN', 'spei']]
spei_avg_ma
```

**Question:**

- What are the pro and cons of this approach (if correct) for this kind of data (precipitation) compared to the main alternatives?

Comment: Please consider asking one question per post. It's better to split your post into two separate posts.